# How to use my Windows 7 home basic 64bit original key to activate Windows 7 ultimate? any ideas please do share

Tags: windows-7, windows

How to use my Windows 7 home basic 64 bit original key to activate Windows 7 ultimate? any ideas please do share. Any ideas? Please do let me know

Comment: So you think people can use the key for any edition on any other costlier edition?

Comment: That's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

Even if you can, it would still be illegal, just like installing a fresh "pirated" copy of Windows. Nothing to do with your original key.